# UICollectionView and other views in one view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a iOS app with a rootViewController. In this view controller there are many different views. now i want a collection view in this view. how should I do this? What I have tried is. Added a uicollection view to the storyboard and set the datasource and delegate to a new uicollectionview controller. the basic stuff works. But I am not able to access the collectionview from the uicollectionview controller view. self.collectionview. Did I forget something? Or is there a better way do handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a plain view controller, not a collection view controller. The latter will have the collection view as its top level `view` property, so you have less flexibility about adding other views to it.

If you want `self.collectionView` you need to declare a property. Don't forget to hook it up in interface builder (plus delegate and datasource).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView * collectionView;
```

Of course you can do the same with more than one collection view. However, in your `UICollectionViewDataSource` and delegate methods you will have to distinguish the two collection views and provide their respective data or react to user interaction accordinng to which collection view was used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the collection view to be managed by your root view controller (i.e. part of its view hierarchy) then forget the collection view controller and set the collections data source and delegate to your root view controller. Then implement the collection view data source and delegate protocols in the root view controller class.

Comment: But what happens if I add an second uicollectionview?

Comment: Presumably you update your controller to manage that, too? It sounds like you've got a lot going on  on this one screen, though... Perhaps you could explain your app a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
        [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];
        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

in cellForItemAtIndexPath.. it should be some thing like below..

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    [titleLabel setText:cellData];
   return cell;
}
```

Refer to following artical, nicely explained.
http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.